# Pass form data as variables to docker command

Tags: php, linux, docker, ansible

I'm trying to run an ansible docker container through a web page but I didn't find a solution, just partially.

I have index.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="adduser.php" method="get">
Server: <input type="text" value="<?php echo $name?>" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

adduser.php

```
<?php
  chdir("aatool"); 
  echo getcwd();
$hosts = $_POST["name"];
echo "$hosts";
// $hosts = escapeshellarg($hosts);
//echo ".escapeshellarg($hosts)";
$output = shell_exec('sudo docker run -i --network=host centos7-ansible ansible-playbook --private-key=ky.pem --extra-vars admin_password=test -e hosts=".escapeshellarg($hosts)." chpass.yml');
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Web page output:

```
/var/www/html/aatool PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

Docker container logs:

```
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

Apache error_log:

```
[:error] [pid 40367] [client x.x.x.x:61812] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: name in /var/www/html/adduser.php on line 4, referer: http://x.x.x.x/
```

If I pass the hosts value directly, like hosts=all, everything works perfect but if I try to get the value from the php form it doesn't want to work. I tried everything that I could find and this code gave me best result but still not working.
I'm hoping that I will find some help here

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your FORM is being submitted by the GET method, but your code checks the $_POST variable. Try setting hosts from $_GET or change the FORM to POST.

Comment: Thanks Matthew but it still doesn't solve my issue. I get the same Web page output, error_log shows nothing, docker container logs has the same output.

Comment: docker inspect 7d8845d1449e
"Cmd": [
                "ansible-playbook",
                "--private-key=ky.pem",
                "--extra-vars",
                "admin_password=test",
                "-e",
                "hosts=.escapeshellarg().",
                "chpass.yml"
Can't add the whole output due to character limit

Comment: You could try changing `-e hosts=".escapeshellarg($hosts)." ` to `-e hosts='.escapeshellarg($host).' ` - there's a mix of single / double quotes meaning the string escapeshellarg is being sent to docker

Comment: I worked with single quotes...and I wanted to try that but i was sure it doesn't make sense :) Thanks